# Jest stops executing expect statements after first failure

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

In a test, I have the following `expect` statement in a loop that should execute twice:

`expect(nr).toEqual(res.body.items[index]);`

On the first iteration, if the test fails, however, jest does not execute the loop again.

If I cchange it to to one that passes, jest executes it for each loop iteration:

`expect(nr).toEqual(res.body.items[index]);`

Here's the code with more context:

```
describe('Recipe', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {});
    beforeEach(async () => {});
    afterEach(async () => {});

    it('should do proper grouping when GET /recipes?filterId=[...]', async () => {
      // setup

      const res = await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .get(...);

      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
      if (res.body.items) {
        [recipeWithProduct1, recipeWithProduct2].forEach((r, index) => {
          console.log('LLL200 testing', index);
          const nr = { ...r, ...{ updatedAt: '', createdAt: '' } };
          delete nr.store;
          delete nr.creator;
          nr.updatedAt = r.updatedAt.toISOString();
          nr.createdAt = r.createdAt.toISOString();
          nr.filters = nr.filters.map(f => f.id) as any; // TODO: fix this coersion

        //   expect(true).toBe(true); // console.log above prints twice if we uncomment this and 
        // comment the expect below
          expect(nr).toEqual(res.body.items[index]); // fails only once
        });
      }
      expect(res.body.total).toEqual(2);
    })
});
```

How do I get jest to execute all expect statements even if previous ones failed?

I'm on jest version 23.6.0.

Comment: I guess best option is separating your specs (and it's the best practice also to follow while writing test) then expect in two separate `it` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening, because internally `expect` is throwing errors. To make them all run you can separate them in different test cases.

Here's an example of how can an improved version of your tests would look like:

```
describe('Recipe', () => {
    let res;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      res = await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .get();
    });
    beforeEach(async () => {});
    afterEach(async () => {});

    describe('response', () => {

      describe.each([
        [recipeWithProduct1, 0],
        [recipeWithProduct2, 1]
      ])('receipe %j %#', (receipe, index) => {
        it(`should match res.body.items[${index}]`, () => {
          expect(res.body.items[index]).toEqual(
            expect.objectContaining({
              ...receipe,
              createdAt: receipe.createdAt.toISOString(),
              updatedAt: receipe.updatedAt.toISOString(),
            })
          );
        })
      })

      it('should have status 200', () => {
        expect(res).toHaveProperty('status', 200)
      })

      it('should have body.total', () => {
        expect(res).toHaveProperty('body.total', 2);
      })
    })
});
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/SimultaneousThoroughLevels?lite=&classroom_template=&outputonly=&fileName=)

Comment: Any evidence of `internally expect is throwing errors`?

Comment: [There it is](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/toThrowMatchers.ts), and you can try wrapping falsy assertion in try catch

Comment: I'm running into issues since recipeWithProduct1 is created in a beforeEach() block. `recipe` inside the `each` block ends up undefined. Thoughts?

Comment: You can define it in the upper scope, as I have with res, and in beforeEach just set it's value

Comment: I tried that: https://gist.github.com/hgezim/46aa401edb58085a7c44c309ea4829ae .`recipe` in the `each` look ends up undefined.

Comment: @Gezim the `describe` and `it` are evaluated in the sync context and I've referenced variables with assigned data. [this approach may solve your problem](https://gist.github.com/Teneff/7fa906e5ea6a356082641aa82f9b4ce5)